# Preventing iOS clock from stopping

Tags: ios, multithreading, performance

I have noticed that during very processor or memory intensive processes that my app is running, notably during initial download or executing a query, the clock inside the status bar will stop running and stay at the time that the process started.  Is there any way to prevent this from happening, in case something like this causes the app to be rejected?  I don't have any code to provide, as I am unsure to where the app does this at exactly.

Comment: Are you doing this downloads on the main thread? or using GCD?

Comment: It's all done in the main thread, only media downloads are being executed in background threads.

Comment: @CBredlow Don't EVER, EVER, do processor intensive work on the main thread. NEVER.

Comment: Any interactions with UIKit (modifying views, etc) should be done on the main thread because that is the only thread where drawing can occur. You should offload whatever else you can to a background thread. If the clock in the status bar lags long enough for you to notice it, there must be something very intensive locking up the main thread.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses, I've started moving things back to background threads, and noticing improvements. I haven't done much with threading in the first place, so a bit unfamiliar with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering your comment, you should not perform memory-intensive or cpu-intensive work on the main thread.  Only interactions with UI should be performed on the main thread, otherwise the UI will seem frozen, including your app and status bar.